# Power Builder 12.5 - Passing the variable value of an auto instantiate object to window

Tags: powerbuilder

I want to pass the value from non visual object, *nvo_test* to window in Power Builder.
FYI, this non visual object is autoinstantiated!

In my non visual object, I have an instance variable *Long il_val* with default value *1*.
The value of *il_val* will be changed accordingly, let's say it is set to 4 for now.
The value will be set in one of the event in the nvo_test, before do setFilter() and filter()

After the value of *il_val* been set to 4, it will trigger the event in window. I code like this in my window

```
Long l_val
nvo_test    nvo
l_val = nvo.il_row
```

However, *l_val* returns 1 instead of 4.

May I know what's wrong? Did I make a mistake or I miss something out?

Any input are highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Where do you set il_row to 4?  If you have code in the constructor event it will not be processed since it is autoinstantiated.

Comment: Hi, il_row = 4 is set in one of the event in the nvo

Answer (score 0):

You aren't specifying where that instance variable is set to 4.  In your example code you are getting the value immediately after declaring the non-visual, and you said the default is 1, therefore the program is working like expected.  If you are setting the instance variable elsewhere, perhaps the constructor, then maybe what Matt answered will help you.

I can't tell what you are doing, but might be useful to know that autoinstantiate behaves differently. Maybe in your case autoinstantiate is hurting you.  From the PowerBuilder help:

**Autoinstantiated objects**
If you want a user object that has methods and inheritance but want the memory allocation of a structure, you can define an autoinstantiated object.

You do not have to create and destroy autoinstantiated objects. Like structures, they are created when they are declared and destroyed when they go out of scope. However, because assignment for autoinstantiated objects behaves like structures, the copies made of the object can be a drawback.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to reply to Matt’s, but I’m way too verbose to fit into a comment.

Matt’s on the right track, but hasn’t pointed out the base problem. Auto-instantiates aren’t like other objects that have an implicit global variable, so when you declare a variable of w_emp, you’re magically pointing at your one live instance of w_emp. (There’s tons of hidden challenges with implicit global variables, but that’s another topic.) Instead, what you’re doing above in declaring a local variable is creating a *new* instance of nvo_test, so as Matt says, between line 2 (declaring the new variable/creating a new instance) & 3 (accessing il_row) of this script, you haven’t changed il_row in *this new instance* of nvo_test. Sounds like you need your ai-nvo to be an instance variable on the window, and reference that instance variable in the above script instead of declaring a local variable and implicitly creating a new instance.

Good luck.